# Android view image intent not displaying image

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to tap an image view, and open that image inside the default photo viewer:

```
void handleOpenImage(){
    try {
        File temp = File.createTempFile("myImage", ".png");
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) attachedImageView.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(temp);
        boolean success = bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
        if(!success){
            throw new Exception();
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(temp), "image/*");
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, when I call this function, a gallery activity starts, but doesn't display my image. The image file is created successfully at the temp path, double checked that. Why isn't the intent working?

Comment: instead of startActivity(intent) use this one and check if it i opening in other app,


startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,  "Select Picture"));

Comment: @Vickyexpert oh sorry just got what you meant. ignore my previous comment. will try.

Comment: @Vickyexpert tried it, I'm getting the same thing: I select Gallery, it opens, but the picture isn't displayed. I'm left with an empty Gallery activity

Comment: No no don't select gallery, for testing purpose select another app and check is image there ?

Comment: What is the absolute path of `temp`?

Comment: @Vickyexpert there is only Gallery and Photos. when I tap Photos, it says Media not found. This is just a test device, I'm not using this device so there aren't any apps installed other than stock apps.

Comment: @ValentinKuhn `/data/data/MY_APPS_IDENTIFIER/cache/ulouder-1004534880.png`

Comment: that's internal for your app, other apps can't access it (at least without root). Try some public location for your temp file

Comment: it's a security feature. BTW sorry for the late answer

Comment: @ValentinKuhn yep, that was it. you can post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I asked in the comments, the absolute path of the `temp` file was `/data/data/MY_APPS_IDENTIFIER/cache/ulouder-1004534880.png`.
This path ist in the private space each app has and cannot be accessed by other apps for security reasons.

By saving the `temp` file to another location, the gallery app can access it and displays the image correctly.